# create request object in POJO class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I am trying to get request object in POJO class. Is there any way to do it.One way is to get from passing request object  as a parameter from Struts framework overidden methods.But how can I create a request object in POJO class.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Struts version? What do you mean by *how can I create a request object in POJO class*? If you can get it in controller what is the problem passing it to your POJO?

Comment: Why would you *want* to?!